# How to truncate text via CSS at the beginning of a sentence, not the end?

Tags: html, css, styling

Just wondering if this is possible in purely just CSS. I want to truncate some text for a file uploader so that it doesn't overflow. The text that displays the file name is styled with the following CSS:

```
span {
  margin-left: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 50ch;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  font-style: italic;
  background: var(--color-light-gray);
  padding: 3px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

With this code, if you upload a file called something like:

`Long_file_name_blah_blah_blah.pdf`

It will truncate to something like:

`Long_file_name_bl...`

This is fine, however since it's a file uploader I'd prefer it if the file extension was visible after truncation, so I'm thinking I want to truncate it from the beginning of the file name, that way the same file above would look like:

`...lah_blah_blah.pdf`

However I can't find a way to do it in pure CSS. I could do this in javascript but I was wondering if there was a way to do it just with HTML and CSS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `direction: rtl;` :

```css
span {
  margin-left: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 50ch;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  font-style: italic;
  background: var(--color-light-gray);
  padding: 3px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<span>testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest.pdf</span>
```

Comment: beware: a coworker recently found that this solution breaks if the text in your span starts with a slash, for example. this should NOT be considered a reliable solution.